# Prove if the set is closed? Bounded? Compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{Q},d)$ where $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the rational numbers and $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.  Let $$E:=\{x \in\mathbb{Q}:x>0, 2<x^2<3\}$$

Is $E$ closed and bounded in $\mathbb{Q}?$  Is it compact?  Justify your answers.

Comment: Can you show it is bounded?

Comment: My immediate assumption is I will end up with it closed and bounded but not equicontinuous?  I dont know how to approach this.  This is not homework--I am studying for one of my comps and am stumped

Comment: @Alyse Where does "equicontinuous" come from?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of the wrong thing.  we know that x is between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, so then is bounded

Comment: For compactness, consider the open cover given by $A_n=(x_n,y_n)$ where $x_n$ approaches $\sqrt{2}$ from the right and $y_n$ approaches $\sqrt{3}$ from the left.

Comment: Is that also breaking the closed part?  I mean we know closed and bounded if and only if compact

Comment: @Alyse That is true for $\Bbb R$; not $\Bbb Q$, careful!

Comment: @Jared I'm trying to find a union of two open subcovers of $A_n$ to show it's compact. But why does $x_n$ have to approach $\sqrt{2}$ from the right and $y_n$ approach $\sqrt{3}$ from the left? I thought it was from the left and right respectively since we want two open subcovers for the cover of $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: You should have no trouble deciding whether $E$ is bounded in $\Bbb Q$. To decide whether it’s closed in $\Bbb Q$, ask yourself whether $\Bbb Q\setminus E$ is open in $\Bbb Q$: can you find an open set $U$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $U\cap\Bbb Q=\Bbb Q\setminus E$? Remember, $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt3$ are irrational.

For compactness, does the sequence $\langle 1.7,1.73,1.732,1.7320,1.73205,\dots\rangle$ in $E$ have a convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

About boundness when do you call a set unbounded? What is your intuition about this set? Can a $x\in E$ be too much large?

Regarding compactness, a characterization of compact metric spaces is:

> $(X,d)$ is compact iff every sequence has a convergent subsequence

Does it happen in the set $E$? Can you find a sequence of elements in $E$ which does not converge in $E$?

Comment: That really isn’t a definition of compactness: it’s the definition of *sequential* compactness, which happens to be equivalent to compactness in metric spaces (but not in general).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Note he wrote $(X,d)$, not $(X,\tau)$, so it is clear $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

Comment: @Peter: I’m aware of that. It’s still at best misleading and at worst simply wrong to say that this is a definition of compactness.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Fair enough. It is a possible definition in *metric spaces*, but you're right. Chat?

Comment: I think now any doubt has been vanished. In a book of Topology of Metric Spaces I had firstly seen this as a definition. In my opinion, it is definitely easier for undergraduate students to understand and use this characterization, rather than the original definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is a metric space.  A compact metric space is necessarily complete.  This will tell you about compactness.

Answer (score 0):

It is not closed. You can always find a sequence of $x \in E$ such that converge to a real number.

Comment: But you need to explain why there is a sequence of elements of $E$ whose limit is not in $E$.

Comment: It is a hint for him to solve the problem. I do not pretend to do his hw :P. Anyway, there is an answer already showing this.